# Adding form labels with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, forms, greasemonkey, label

A vendor's web app requires me to select a thumbnail in a radio group, then hit Save, and  I must do this over 300 times. And they didn't have the decency to make the radio button content clickable. I thought GM would allow me to do this, but I'm at a loss on how to write the script. And if I could get the radio button to go ahead and fire the submit button, all the better. Here's the code:

```
<div id="image1" class="image_selection">
<input type="radio" id="" class="" name="selectimageid" value="1"/>
<img id="1" class="thumb" src="/images/thumb1.jpg" /> 
</div>

<div id="image2" class="image_selection">
<input type="radio" id="" class="" name="selectimageid" value="2"/>
<img id="2" class="thumb" src="/images/thumb2.jpg" /> 
</div>

<input type="submit" id="" class="save_button" name="" value="" />
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the labels, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery's `.wrap()` function](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=wrap).  Something like this should do it:

```
$("input[name='selectimageid']").wrap ('<label></label>');
```

---

However, I assume that you want the thumbnails to be a clickable part of the label.  A **complete working Greasemonkey script** for that is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var imgRadioBtns = $("input[name='selectimageid']");

imgRadioBtns.each ( function () {
    var radBtn  = $(this);
    var toWrap  = radBtn.nextAll ("img.thumb").addBack ();

    toWrap.wrapAll ('<label></label>');
} );
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you!!! I couldn't have begun to figure that out on my own, not on my deadline. Thanks again.